# Two mobile apps use the same set of Web APIs and database, how to differentiate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mobile-application, asp.net-web-api2

We are developing two mobile apps, one (A) for a group of people, another (B) for another group of people.

These two mobile apps use the same set of Web APIs, although some APIs may only be used one group and vice versa. In other words, we have just one Web API project.

Both apps' user need to register and (later) login with username and password. We save all users in the same AspNetUsers table.

Now I realize there is a problem. A user registered on app A can login on app B and a user registerd on app B can login on app A.

How do I solve this problem? Do we require the apps to send a code to our API so that our API know if its from A or B?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net membership has user roles, you can use it to [authorize](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) users to some parts of your api.

- Give "GroupA" or "GroupB" role to a user during registration.
- Properly set principals after authenticate.
- Use **System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute** to authorize

---

```
  public class FooController : ApiController
  {
    [Authorize(Roles = "GroupA")]
    public void GetOnlyForGroupA(){}

    [Authorize(Roles = "GroupB")]
    public void GetOnlyForGroupB(){}

    public void GetForBoth(){}
  }
```